# Nginx image not found fallback

Tags: nginx, replace, http-status-code-404, fallback

My site have many images /image/test/manyfile.jpg and now day I have /image/test/manyfile_large.jpg, but not all .jpg have _large.jpg.

So my idea is use Nginx to check manyfile_large.jpg file, if not exist then rewrite or redirect to manyfile.jpg

Can anyone give an example config?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Are these files in the same directory? Is the URI based on the name of the non-_large file?

Comment: @RichardSmith yes, the same directory, for example: /image/test/dog.jpg, /image/test/dog_large.jpg, /image/test/cat.jpg, /image/test/cat_large.jpg, /image/test/bird.jpg, but no /image/test/bird_large.jpg. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try_files` to test for the existence of one or more files. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

First you need to capture the components of the URI so that you can construct the two filename variants to try.

I am not sure if the examples in your question and comment are URIs or pathnames. In the following example, the URI is `/image/foo/bar.jpg` and the corresponding files are located at `/path/to/image/foo/bar.jpg` and (optional) `/path/to/image/foo/bar_large.jpg`.

For example:

```
location ~ ^(/image/.+)\.(jpg|png|svg)$ {
    root /path/to;

    try_files $1_large.$2 $1.$2 =404;
}
```

The block will return the large variant if it exists, then the regular variant if it exists, then a 404 status if neither exist.

The order of regular expression `location` blocks is significant, as the first block with a matching regular expression is used to process the request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.